# A man tests for HIV. What is the predictive probability that his second test is negative?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Can anyone help with this question ?

> In a population, it is estimated HIV prevalence to be $\lambda$.
> For a new test for HIV:
>
> - $\theta$ is the probability of an HIV positive person to test positive
> - $\eta$ is the probability an HIV negative person tests positive in this test.
>
> A person takes the test to check whether they have HIV, he tests positive.
>
> What is the predictive probability he tests negative on the second test?

Assumption: Repeat tests on the same person are conditionally independent.

From my notes predictive probability is given as:

> $P(\tilde{Y} = \tilde{y} | Y = y) = \int p(\tilde{y}|\tau) p(\theta|\tau)$
> here $\tilde{Y}$ is the unknown observable, $y$ is the observed data and $\eta$ the unknown.

I am interested in the probability of the second test is negative, given that the first test is positive,without knowing if the man really has HIV or not.

To facilitate this I define:

> - $y_1$ as the event of the first test being positive and
> - $\tilde{y_{2}}$ as the second test being negative

Would this adaption to the formula given above be the correct/best approach to this problem ?

> $p(\tilde{y_{2}}, y_{1}|\tau) = p(\tilde{y_{2}}|\tau) p(y_{1}|\tau)p(\tau) $
> and this is really
> $\propto p(\tilde{y_{2}}|\tau) p(\tau|y_{1})$

I've gotten for the $p(\tau|y_{1})$ from Bayes' theorem:

$$p(\tau|y_{1}) = \frac{p(\tau)p(y_1|\tau)}{p(y_1)} \\
= \frac{\lambda \theta}{ \lambda \theta + \eta (1 - \lambda) }$$

How could I then find $p(\tilde{y_{2}}|\tau)$ ? Is this the correct approach ?

Any hints are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it hard to follow your calculations, partly because you didn’t introduce $\tau$ and your integrals don’t indicate their integration variables. Here’s one way to do this:

\begin{eqnarray}
P(\text{2nd test $-$}\mid \text{1st test +})
&=&
\sum_{\sigma\in\{+,-\}}P(\text{2nd test $-$}\mid\text{1st test +},\text{HIV}\sigma)P(\text{HIV}\sigma\mid\text{1st test +})
\\
&=&
\sum_{\sigma\in\{+,-\}}P(\text{2nd test $-$}\mid\text{HIV}\sigma)P(\text{HIV}\sigma\mid\text{1st test +})
\\
&=&
\sum_{\sigma\in\{+,-\}}P(\text{2nd test $-$}\mid\text{HIV}\sigma)\frac{P(\text{1st test +}\mid\text{HIV}\sigma)P(\text{HIV}\sigma)}{\sum_{\rho\in\{+,-\}}P(\text{1st test +}\mid\text{HIV}\rho)P(\text{HIV}\rho)}
\\
&=&
\frac{\sum_{\sigma\in\{+,-\}}P(\text{2nd test $-$}\mid\text{HIV}\sigma)P(\text{1st test +}\mid\text{HIV}\sigma)P(\text{HIV}\sigma)}{\sum_{\rho\in\{+,-\}}P(\text{1st test +}\mid\text{HIV}\rho)P(\text{HIV}\rho)}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where the first equality applies the law of total probability, the second equality applies your assumption of conditional independence of multiple tests, the third equality applies Bayes’ theorem to express $P(\text{HIV}\mu\mid\text{1st test +})$ in terms of known quantities, and the fourth equality is just a rearrangement of the sum.

Another way to get the same result is by applying the law of total probability to both the numerator and the denominator in

$$
P(\text{2nd test $-$}\mid \text{1st test +})=\frac{P(\text{2nd test $-$}\cap \text{1st test +})}{P(\text{1st test +})}\;.
$$

Plugging in your variables yields

\begin{eqnarray}
P(\text{2nd test $-$}\mid \text{1st test +})
&=&
\frac{(1-\theta)\theta\lambda+(1-\eta)\eta(1-\lambda)}{\theta\lambda+\eta(1-\lambda)}\;.
\end{eqnarray}